# Name Property in Xaringan Slides

Tags: r, xaringan, remarkjs

I am probably missing something very obvious, but when creating a new slide in xaringan, what does name do?  For example `name: setup`, or `name:usecourse` or `name:ninja` set at the start of the slide?

I can't find references in the custom css so I am really not sure what this is doing.

To see an example of how this is being used:  https://github.com/rstudio-education/arm-workshop-rsc2019/blob/master/static/slides/xaringan.Rmd

And the repo where the custom css files live: https://github.com/rstudio-education/arm-workshop-rsc2019/tree/master/static/slides/css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you name a slide, an id will be appended to the slide. So say now you want to go to the slide named `ninja` from another slide (within the same presentation) then you can refer to it by `[click here](#ninja)`.

Also if you append `#ninja` to your slide URL then it will go directly to that slide, e.g. `yourslides.html#ninja`.

You can also use named slides as a template for other slides. E.g.

```
name: ninja

Institute Logo (say)

---

template: ninja

Content to be appended
```